# How the iter() method work in the str class?

Tags: python

Why when you call the `__next__()` method on `str` it says it does not have this method ...

```
b = 'hello'
b.__next__()  # give AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__next__'
a = iter(b)
a.__next__() # output == 'h'
```

Does not the `__iter__()` method return self?
Well, if it returns self, it is a string that does not have the `__next__()` method?

So how does  return  `"h"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`iter`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter) only returns its argument if the value is an iterator. `str` is *not* an iterator; it is an iterable whose `__iter__` method returns a `str_iterator` object.

```
>>> a = iter(b)
>>> type(a)
<class 'str_iterator'>
```

The `str_iterator` object implements `__next__`, and maintains iteration state separate from any other iterator over the same object.

```
>>> b = 'hello'
>>> a1 = iter(b)
>>> a2 = iter(b)
>>> next(a1)
'h'
>>> next(a2)
'h'
>>> next(a2)
'e'
>>> next(a2)
'l'
>>> next(a1)
'e'
```

---

You could picture `str_iterator` being defined something like

```
class str_iterator:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i == len(self.s):
            raise StopIteration
        i = self.i
        self.i += 1
        return self.s[i]

 class str:

     ...

     def __iter__(s):
         return str_iterator(s)
```

The iterator remembers is position in the string between calls to `__next__`. The job of `__next__` is to advance the "pointer" and to return the character at the correct position.

Comment: So how does it work?
If I understand correctly, it means sending an object of class str_iterator?
Can I see the code of this class to better understand?

Comment: It's built into the interpreter, like `str` itself. You can *think* of it as a wrapper around the `str` object, though; I'll add a rough, pure-Python equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now
That was the point

Comment: Sir I think `if self.i == len(self.s):` should be `if self.i >= len(self.s):`. In order to next calls of `next()`  gives correct exception type.

Comment: If `StopIteration` gets raised, `self.i` can't be incremented again, so `self.i == len(self.s)` will always be true.

Answer (score 5):

Don't confuse "iterators" with "iterables":

1- Iterables implement iterables' protocol which is `__iter__`.

2- Iterators implement iterators' protocol which is `__iter__` and `__next__`.

You can see that iterators are iterables themselves but the reverse is not True.

In your case, `b` is "iterable" not "iterator". You should call `iter()` to get iterator back.

> Does not the `__iter__()` method return self?

If the object is "iterator" Yes. If the object is "iterable" No, it should return iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first line:

`b = 'hello'`

means that `b` is a `str` and it doesn't have a `__next__()` method.

The next line:

`a = iter(b)`

means that now `a` is a `str_iterator` which *does* have a `__next__()` method.

And finally:

`a.__next__()`

is just calling `__next__()` on a `str_iterator` which returns what it wants to return and `a` is still a `str_iterator`.

Comment: Quibble: `iter` is not a type; `a` is a `str_iterator`, which implements the iterator protocol.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, I *knew* someone would know the exact type.